# Retrieve mailchimp list details via ajax (iron-ajax, polymer)

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, mailchimp

I am trying to call the mailchimp API to show details of a list but I can't figure out how to send the auth credentials to show the list. I've tried a few things, I'm not really sure if I'm on the right track. This is what I've tried:

```
<iron-ajax
    auto
    url='https://us3.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{{listid}}'
    handle-as='json'
    method='get'
    headers='{"Authorization": "Basic base64credentials"}'
    debounce-duration='300'
    last-response='{{json}}'></iron-ajax>


<iron-ajax
    auto
    url='https://us3.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{{listid}}'
    handle-as='json'
    method='get'
    headers='{"user": "username:apikey"}'
    debounce-duration='300'
    last-response='{{json}}'></iron-ajax>


<iron-ajax
    auto
    url='https://us3.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{{listid}}'
    handle-as='json'
    method='get'
    headers='{"Authorization": "Basic username:apikey"}'
    debounce-duration='300'
    last-response='{{json}}'></iron-ajax>
```

Comment: Why 3 ajax requests ? go with the 2nd one with http authentication

Comment: Those are just 3 samples of things I've tried out. Neither of them worked for me, sorry should have clarified. So is #2 the right approach, meaning something else is most likely the cause of it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `btoa` function:

```
<iron-ajax
auto
url='https://us3.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{{listid}}'
handle-as='json'
method='get'
headers='{"Authorization": "Basic [[basicAuth(username, apiKey)]]"}'
debounce-duration='300'
last-response='{{json}}'></iron-ajax>
<script>
    Polymer({
        ...
        basicAuth(username, password) {
            return window.btoa(username + ':' + password)
        },
        ...
    });
</script>
```